# Could someone explain the use of qunit-fixture when unit testing with QUnit?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I am just getting started with QUnit for ui testing, so I'm sure I am missing some fundamental use case for qunit-fixture. I thought it would be useful for testing DOM manipulation, but then I realized none of my DOM manipulating functions know anything about qunit-fixture (nor should they?).

Example:

```
<div id="container">
    <form id="my-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="field1" id="field1">
        <input type="hidden" name="field2" id="field2">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
```

I am passing URL parameters to a function to populate this form. If those params do not exist, I wish to remove the field so that `JQuery.serialize()` does not bundle up an empty field.

```
function populate(params){
    if( params.field1 ){
        $("#field1").val(params.field1);
    } else {
        $("#field1").remove();
    }
    if( params.field2 ){
        $("#field2").val(params.field2);
    } else {
        $("#field2").remove();
    }
}
```

My original thought was "oh, cool. I can use `qunit-fixture` to repeatedly emulate my form!" like so:

```
QUnit.test("populate - field1=text", function(assert){
    $("#qunit-fixture").html($("#container").html());
    populate( {field1: "text"} );

    assert.deepEqual($("#field1").val(), "text");
    assert.deepEqual($("#field2").val(), undefined);
});

QUnit.test("populate - field1="text", function(assert){
    $("#qunit-fixture").html($("#container").html());
    populate( {field1: "text", field2: "text"} );

    assert.deepEqual($("#field1").val(), "text");
    assert.deepEqual($("#field2").val(), "text");
});
```

This of course fails, because the first test's call to `populate()` alters the DOM and removes `#field2` from the pages's main form in addition to the copy that was placed into `qunit-fixture` (non-unique IDs.. yikes).

So what am I missing? I am really like the ability to test logic modules with QUnit and am finally starting to see the merits of a more test driven development style. I would love to be able to test my DOM manipulation as well.

NOTE: This is a dumbed down example. The actual DOM manipulation in my project is significantly more complex, hence the desire to test it.

Comment: have you considered placing an iframe in the qunit-fixture, it will isolate test environment and supporting code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `qunit-fixture` element is a container for some HTML that your tests can assert against.  After each test, QUnit will reset it back to what it was before the test started, so that the next test can run without having to worry about what the previous test added or removed.

Of course, if your tests start making modifications to elements outside `qunit-fixture`, then you will start to see tests affecting other tests, so try not to do this.

In your case, you are creating an empty `qunit-fixture` div and copying the contents in from another div.  A better approach would be to use the `qunit-fixture` element to contain the HTML that you want to test against, for example:

```
<div id="qunit-fixture">
    <div id="container">
        <form id="my-form">
            <input type="hidden" name="field1" id="field1">
            <input type="hidden" name="field2" id="field2">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

(I don't know if you need the container div.  I've kept it in the example above, but if it's not necessary, feel free to get rid of it.)

As you no longer need to copy the HTML from the container div into the `qunit-fixture` div, you can delete these lines from your tests:

```
    $("#qunit-fixture").html($("#container").html());
```

You also no longer have the problem of duplicate IDs, and as QUnit would be resetting the `qunit-fixture` after each test, you shouldn't have the problem of one of your tests affecting another.

The intention with QUnit is that you run it from a page you've created for specifically for testing purposes.  This page should look like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- load various JS and CSS files -->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture">
    <!-- sample markup for testing against -->
  </div>
</body>
```

As there's no markup outside `qunit-fixture`, other than the `qunit` div, which QUnit will use for the test results, there's no "portion of the page outside `qunit-fixture`", as you write in your comment, nor is there any duplication of IDs.

Comment: This does not eliminate the problem of duplicate IDs as the IDs are still present in the portion of the page outside of qunit-fixture. Also, `populate()` still mangles that portion of the DOM. It also seems like a huge performance hit (page size) to basically duplicate all markup into qunit-fixture.

Comment: @thedarklord47: it seems we're on quite the same wavelength. As far as I can tell, QUnit is intended to be used on a static HTML page of the form I've included in my edited answer.  Is this how you are running QUnit?  If not, how are you running it?  Where does you HTML come from?

Comment: page is not static. its part of a laravel web app with additional Handlebars templates. That should not matter though. My question is: by definition, a function that manipulates the DOM (the function I want to test), will manipulate the DOM. Adding a hidden `qunit-fixture` that gets reset each test, does not change that fact. Additionally, inserting markup into `qunit-fixture` to emulate what is going on in the page, results in non-unique IDs and is clearly not the way to do it. Are you saying QUnit is not intended to be run on a real page at all? Like I need to build a separate test sandbox?

Comment: @thedarklord47: yes, I would say that QUnit isn't intended to be run on a real page.  I'm afraid I haven't used Laravel nor Handlebars so I don't know how much work putting together a test sandbox will be for you.

Comment: ah. well.. not super easy, but that makes a lot more sense. thank you for the explanation

Comment: How are we supposed to view the HTML elements when they in the same file as the QUnit test code?  For example if I want to test file uploading is there a way I could tell Qunit to automatically invoke the input element to do so?

Comment: @kiwicomb123: sorry, but if you have a separate question to ask, please ask a separate question.